# How should I structure a GAE datastore to be able to grab professions related to a keyword?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, database-design, google-cloud-datastore

If someone searches for "teeth doctor", I would like to return entries from a google app engine datastore for dentists. Similarly, "foot doctor" would return podiatrists, "childrens' doctor" pediatrician, etc.

How should I find related keywords, and should I store them with the doctor entries, in a separate table, or grab them on request?

I'm thinking of having one entity for the professionals - it would include their name, location, contact info, etc, but most importantly, the formal name for their profession. And, another table for a relation of words to professions. For example, "teeth" would map to dentist, but also orthodontist. Would this be the best way to go about it?

Also, is there a way to have google sort the results by multiple things? I would like to list the most relevant results, but also have priority on slightly less-related, but closer doctors. For example, if a user searches for "teeth", I would want the results to be in the order of: 1. A dentist 0.5 miles away, 2. An orthadontist 0.2 miles away, and 3. A dentist 5 miles away. What I'm currently thinking for this is keeping track of the estimated percent-likelihood that a searched keyword is meant to return a certain profession and then calculate that into the distance calculator that I would be using and sorting by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with having a profession kind and a professional kind. Professional entities then reference the applicable profession. Profession entities would contain your keywords. You could then use the new app engine search feature to index and search professions ([Search Overview (Python)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview)) and use the results to look up professionals. Indexing your professionals this way as well would give you some/all of the location based searching you want to implement.